# Is there a way to update a file in SVN from a non-working copy of the file?

Tags: svn

I have an interesting issue with our continuous deployment/SVN setup.

We have a configuration file that is modifiable via one of our QA/Test website deployments. What happens is when we release code to QA, our continuous deployment system will deploy it to several QA servers, and the QA folks will test it. As part of the testing scenarios, they will modify a configuration file that will eventually need to be re-intergrated into our SVN repository in preparation for the next production release.

I'm trying to find a way to automate getting that file into SVN. The place where they modify it is an actual deployed site, it's not part of a working copy of an SVN repository.

Is there a way to update a file in an SVN repository from a file that is not at all attached to SVN (ie, it's not a working copy of the file). I basically want a command line utility that I can call that says "take myfile.xml and check it into repository  and overwrite whatever is there."

We're doing it manually now, and that works, but is obviously less than ideal.

Comment: copy into a working copy, then you can commit it normally, that is the only way

Comment: Copying the modified file into the working copy isn't working - SVN doesn't pick up the copied file as being modified, so the commit doesn't work. Is there a way to flag it or otherwise force it to commit?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a cron job to rcp the file to your development server. You will have a checkedout copy in dev server. The script under cron will copy the file to the working copy in dev server (essentially overwrite as you said). You can then checkin  the file from the dev server.